# Networkx: how to add edges to graph using node attributes

Tags: python, networkx

I have a pos-tag list of word in a csv file, each word with his pos tag for example:

[(what,WP)
(makes,VBZ)
(them,PRP)
(do,VB)
(it,PRP)]
etc...

I want the nodes to be the TAG (WP,VBZ,PRP..) and the attributes the edges in a consecutive form for example the list of edges will be:

[(what,makes)
(makes,them)
(them,do)
(do,it)]
it...
So the I could remove duplicated nodes but still have all the attributes going out of the node and in..
I have this so far

```
G=nx.MultiGraph()
files = glob.glob('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/prueba3/*.csv')
for path in files:
dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
with open ('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/prueba3/%s' %filename) as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            new_node = row[1]               
            new_attributes = row[:1]
            G.add_node(new_node, my_attributes=new_attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` to create the appropriate pairings between consecutive words in the sentence makes this simple. I also use `add_edge` instead since this  automatically adds the nodes as well. Note the third parameter of `add_edge` allows you to take in a `key` parameter that can be used to identify that unique edge in a `nx.MultiGraph` object. I am not sure what exactly is the format of your `.csv` file, so I am just passing in a sentence as a list containing tuples of `(word, POS)` for the following example. Hope this helps!

```
from collections import defaultdict
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiGraph()

sentence = [
    ("what", "WP"), 
    ("makes", "VBZ"),
    ("them", "PRP"), 
    ("do", "VB"),
    ("it", "PRP"),
]

for pair0, pair1 in zip(sentence[:-1], sentence[1:]):
    w0, t0 = pair0
    w1, t1 = pair1
    edge_key = "{0} {1}".format(w0, w1)
    G.add_edge(t0, t1, edge_key)

print(G.nodes)#['WP', 'VBZ', 'PRP', 'VB']
print(G.edges)#[('WP', 'VBZ', 'what makes'), ('VBZ', 'PRP', 'makes them'), ('PRP', 'VB', 'them do'), ('PRP', 'VB', 'do it')]
```